# FancyBox (fancyapps) content on top

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox-3

I am using fancyBox v3.5.6 from fancyApps.

Is there any posibility to disable auto centering and move the content on top? I wasn't able to find anything that disable center aligning and move the content up.

```js
    var dialogMessage = '<div>This is a message</div';
       $.fancybox.open(dialogMessage,{
        //maybe here some option?
      });
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

fancybox v3 uses pseudo element trick for vertical centering (you can google for more info, for example, see #4 here - https://blog.logrocket.com/13-ways-to-vertical-center-in-2018-cb6e98ed8a40). So, you can hide that element and then your content will be right at the top. You could do that for all slides or using `slideClass` option to apply custom class name when needed, for example -

JS

```
$.fancybox.open({
  src : '<div class="message"><h2>Hello!</h2><p>You are awesome!</p></div>',
  type : 'html',
  slideClass : 'fancybox-top'
});
```

CSS

```
.fancybox-top::before {
  display: none;
}
```

DEMO

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/arqzYN

Comment: I tried your exmaple. It still goes vertical center.

Comment: Then also try to change from `display: inline-block;` to `display: block` for `.fancybox-content`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean vertically centering? Unfortunately, looks like there is no option to disable it, so you can do it by applying the following css to the `.fancybox-content` class in which the box is in, I made it fill the content by default but you can set your desired width if you wish as well as for the top :

```
.fancybox-content {
   top: 15px !important;
   position: absolute !important;
   right: 0 !important;
   left: 0 !important;
   margin: auto !important;
   width: fit-content !important;
   width: -moz-fit-content !important;
}
```

Example in the snippet below :

```js
var dialogMessage = '<div>This is a message</div';
       $.fancybox.open(dialogMessage,{
        //maybe here some option?
      });
```

```css
.fancybox-content {
    top: 15px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    margin: auto !important;
    width: fit-content !important;
    width: -moz-fit-content !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution works, but try on extra long content, it will not look so great.

Comment: That's why I mentionned he can set a fixed width if he doesn't want the box to adapt to a long text.